# Where do I edit the user profile with Buddypress?

Tags: buddypress

Hey for some reason i cannot find the file to edit the appearance of the user profiles with buddypress.

`Mysite.com/members/USER`

where do i edit the profile, like adding `<div>` contents

Answer (score 1):

Found it, for some reason the template pack did't create a page in the theme for me to edit the profile style but i had to go into the root of the site and edit the `home.php`1 in the folder `single`